# How can I download a utf-8-encoded web page with libcurl, preserving the encoding?

Tags: c++, utf-8, ascii, libcurl

Im trying to get libcurl to download a webpage that is encoded in UTF-8, which is working fine, except for the fact that it converts it to ASCII and screws up some of the characters. Is there an easy way to get it to keep it in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libcurl doesn't translate/convert the data at all so there's actually nothing particular you need to do. Just get it.

Comment: Yeah found this out. Just needed to run it via a function to convert it back into ascii

Answer (score 1):

Check the [CURL options for conversion](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCONVFROMNETWORKFUNCTION). They might have been defined at compilation time.